# How do I hibernate a VM and boot it on a new machine without losing state of processes?

Tags: linux, operating-system, cloud, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I have a linux VM running some processes. I want to pause these processes, shut down my VM and boot this VM on a different machine in such a way that all the previously running processes resume execution from the last state before the VM was shut down. Is this possible ? If yes, how can I achieve this ?

Can hibernation help me achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

First off, What's the hardware?
What host os you using like windows?
What software are you using for the virtual machine?
Where is linux booting off, is it a vmk file?
What kind of storage are you using and have you direct access to it?
You haven't given much information to go by to give exact step by step instructions.

My personal use I have found that it is possible to boot a physical drive with virtualbox, my drive also has a ntfs partition on it but the drive has to be offline on windows for me to boot and have administrator privileges which does not allow access from windows to that partition, if you are only using one physical hard drive I believe this may not be possible or may cause serious failures. If you have another hard drive you can copy the system over to a partition with enough knowledge. [Here is a reference from the arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Moving_an_existing_install_into_(or_out_of)_a_virtual_machine#Moving_out_of_a_VM)

Oh and about hibernation I haven't used but you can read up about [acpid](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpie)

and having the virtual machine software to pass the event on

Comment: Welcome to SO! The first part of your answer is a comment and should be placed there. The second part, you are talking about your experience but did you ask to the question? On the third part, you are giving some information that should be given in a comment. Check when you give an answer that you are replying to the question.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego - all valid points. Just note that `john` has < 50 rep and can't yet post comments (a good thing to point out and be aware of). As for answering the OP's question: the question itself is off-topic here (and should find its way to SuperUser) and needs more clarification before it's answerable.

Comment: @David Makogon, noted. I know that john is a new user with not enough rep points to make comments as I was 2 months ago. I make some comments at that time as answer... but I was indicating [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664804/value-error-in-udf-when-doing-simple-division/57665264#57665264), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680773/excel-advanced-filter-filter-values-greater-than-today/57681374#57681374)... In my personal opinion, new users should be introduce to the system.

Comment: @David thanks for the introduction and pointers, probably made it a bit to rambly and not fully understanding the system as I was just curious how the whole helping thing worked